# Do async responses get stored or processed immediately?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

Say I'm communicating with an API which, for any valid parameter, responds with a very long list. I want to extract the first element of this list for several parameters. My code looks like this (feedback welcome):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

URL = 'https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/trades?symbol='

symbols = ['BTCUSDT', 'ETHBTC', 'ETHUSDT']

async def get_trades(symbols):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [session.get(URL + symbol) for symbol in symbols]
        all_trades = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        trades = [(await x.json())[0] for x in all_trades]
        return trades

await get_trades(symbols)
```

My question is: When running `get_trades`, do the full lists for all parameters get stored somewhere simultaneously, or is each list dealt with and then discarded immediately?

In other words, is `all_trades` something like a list of lists which is first completely created and then iterated over (to extract the first elements) or is it more like an abstract object instructing the compiler what to do when creating `trades`?

I'm asking because, if the responses are indeed first all stored together, this would of course take up unnecessary space as I'm only interested in one element of each list. In this case, how could I modify my code to get rid of this inefficiency?

Comment: Python objects will get garbage collected once there are no more references to them. To parse the json, you need to read the full data into memory. So it will be fully loaded at `(await x.json())`. Once you access the first element, `(await x.json())[0]` there are no more references to the full data, and at some point shortly after the interpreter will dispose of the data. If you want to avoid the full load, you would probably need to stream the response from the `get` call, however, you would have to parse the data yourself, as a partial response would not be a valid json.

Comment: @flakes No, I don't necessarily need to avoid the full load of a _single_ json, especially since I might be interested in other elements as well. My concern was more whether there is a point at which _all_ of the jsons are in the memory, but based on what you say, that is not the case, right? Nothing is being loaded in `all_trades`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all of the responses will be stored in `all_trades`, before being processed in the next lines. To avoid that, you can discard what you don't need before it is collected from all tasks. Approximately this way:

```
async def get_one_trade(session, symbol):
    x = await session.get(URL + symbol)
    return (await x.json())[0]  # discard the rest


async def get_trades(symbols):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [get_one_trade(session, symbol) for symbol in symbols]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


await get_trades(symbols)
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! There's no way to replace `get_one_trade` with a list comprehension inside `get_trades`, right? Like something in the spirit of `tasks = [(await session.get(URL + symbol)).json()[0] for symbol in symbols]`? Because `tasks` needs to contain actual tasks, not just lists, for the following line to work.